# Automatically kill an in-progress compilation when compile is (re)invoked?

Tags: prompt, compile, confirmation

Dozens of times per day I tap `C-x m` to build, then discover something i need to change, change it, tap `C-x m` again, and get a prompt from Emacs:

```
A compilation process is running; kill it? (yes or no)
```

In 25 years of using Emacs I have never *not* wanted to answer yes to that and have wasted thousands upon thousands of keystrokes typing out "yes" to that prompt.

My question is simply: How can we make Emacs automatically kill a an in-progress compilation without prompting for confirmation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(setq compilation-always-kill t)*

Comment: This works great, thank you, and solves the problem in a better way for me. My still-low reputation doesn't permit me to +1 it but i have tapped the "accept answer" button.